# Why are there margins when my canvas is in fullScreen?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was researching making objects fullscreen and can't figure out why there are black margins around my canvas when I call requestFullscreen on it. Why are the margins there and how should I fix my code so the canvas truly covers the full screen when I call requestFullscreen?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
var elem = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* to remove the top and left whitespace */

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* just to be sure these are full screen*/
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Fullscreen</button>
<button onclick="closeFullscreen();">Close Fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: On a phone rn, but at a glance I'd say you are setting your canvas width and height to the size of your viewport before you enter the fullscreen mode, i.e you'll have the size of the address bar etc. that will miss once in fumlscreen mode. You may listene for the resize event to resize your canvas, though you'll need to redraw eveything on it. Alternatively, choose a ratio format and stick to it. (Hard to tell what's best without knowing what you will do on this canvas).

Comment: Hmmm I think I'd want to do a ratio format so I can resize my drawings proportionate to the canvas. How would you set up the ratio format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kaiido said, you are setting the size of the canvas on page load, so it needs to be recalculated once on full screen. You can wrap your drawing logic into a function, and call that function every time the fullscreen status changes:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// Get browser-specific method and event name
var fullscreenProps = whichFullscreen(c);

// Draw on page load
drawCanvas();
// Redraw when going into or leaving fullscreen
c.addEventListener(fullscreenProps.eventName, drawCanvas);

function drawCanvas() {
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}

function openFullscreen() {
  if (fullscreenProps.method) {
    fullscreenProps.method.call(c)
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Going fullscreen failed");
        console.log(err);
      });
  } else {
    console.log("Fullscreen not available");
  }
}

function whichFullscreen(el) {
  if (el.requestFullscreen) {
    return { method: el.requestFullscreen, eventName: "fullscreenchange" };
  }
  if (el.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    return { method: el.mozRequestFullScreen, eventName: "mozfullscreenchange" };
  }
  if (el.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    return { method: el.webkitRequestFullscreen, eventName: "webkitfullscreenchange" };
  }
  if (el.msRequestFullscreen) {
    return { method: el.msRequestFullscreen, eventName: "msfullscreenchange" };
  }
  return { method: null, eventName: null };
}
```

Comment: Better yet to listen for the resize event, fullscreenchange may happen before the page is fully resized

Comment: Nice the above example works great with the window.onresize event. Thanks for the help!